# A question regarding the conditions imposed on an index in the course of the proof of Sylow's theorem I.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Source : Eliott Nicholson ( YT) , Group Theory Playlist, video n° 75, 22:40 [image below]

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=p^{\alpha}m$ with $p$ a prime number  and $m\in \mathbb N$.

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of all subsets of $G$ of order $p^{\alpha}$.

To be proved ( before actually proving Sylow's first theorem)  : $p$ does not divide $ | \mathscr{C}|$.

The number $  | \mathscr{C}|$ can be written as :

$$  | \mathscr{C}|= \prod_{k=0} ^ {p^{\alpha-1}} \frac {n-k} {p^{\alpha}-k}.$$

At this pont it is useful to rewrite $k$ as $k = p^i L$ ,

> with  ***$0\leq i \lt \alpha$***.

My question is : **why has $i$ to be strictly less that $\alpha$?**

[image]

The only explanation I can come up with is  that , if $i=\alpha$ , we have

$p^{\alpha}L = p^{\alpha}-1$

which yelds ( dividing by $ p^{\alpha}$)

$L= 1- \frac{1}{p^{\alpha}}$ ,

meaning that $L$ is a natural number iff $p^{\alpha} =1$, and this last condition is much too restrictive and would make the theorem useless or trivial.

Comment: In the product you go over values of $k$ from $0$ to $p^{\alpha-1}$. Every such $k$ is clearly not divisible by $p^{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the product over $k=0$ to $k=p^{\alpha-1}$. Therefore, if $k=p^{a}K$ for some $a\ge \alpha$ (and some integer $K$ with $p\nmid K$), then $p^a\mid k$, which means $k>p^{\alpha-1}$, a contradiction